# 404 error,not displaying view content in jsp java spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jsp

so I have some JSP views in my Spring Boot code, one of them which I have a problem with is showInfo.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%--
  Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
  User: PC
  Date: 02.05.2022
  Time: 15:20
  To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
--%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<%--@elvariable id="banner" type="java.util.List<pl.coderslab.entity.Banners>"--%>
<%--@elvariable id="rent" type="java.util.List<pl.coderslab.entity.Rents>"--%>
<c:forEach var = "banners" items="${banner}">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Street</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>is Rented</th>
        <th>rented from</th>
        <th>rented until</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>${banners.street}</td>
        <td>${banners.price}</td>
        <td>${banners.is_rented}</td>
        <td>${banners.rents.rented_from}</td>
        <td>${banners.rents.rented_until}</td>
    </tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Wstecz"></td>

</table>
</c:forEach>


</body>
</html>
```

I also have dashboard.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="security" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%--
  Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
  User: PC
  Date: 02.05.2022
  Time: 15:20
  To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
--%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>


<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Dashboard</h1>
<br>


<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Banners</th>
        <th>Localization</th>
    </tr>
    <%--@elvariable id="banners" type="java.util.List<pl.coderslab.entity.Banners>"--%>
    <c:forEach var="banner" items="${banners}">

        <tr>
            <td>Banner</td>
            <td>${banner.street}</td>
            <td><a href="http://localhost:8080/dashboard/info/${banner.id}" >Wiecej informacji</a></td>
            <td> <a href="http://localhost:8080/dashboard/edit/${banner.id}" >Edytuj </a></td>
            <td> <a href="http://localhost:8080/dashboard/delete/${banner.id}" >Usun </a></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>


</table>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is when I click on one of hrefs, it redirects but I have 404 error "Not found". But I have controller to every href, for example showInfo controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard/info/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showInfo(Model model, @PathVariable("id") int id){
        List<Banners> banners = bannerDao.getBannerById(id);
        model.addAttribute("banner", banners);
        return "showInfo";

    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard/info/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String info(){
        return "redirect:/dashboard";
    }
```

I don't know what is problem here. I have @RequestMapping's, all properties and dependencies are included.

Comment: do you deploy the spring boot application as a `jar` ?

Comment: It's a spring-boot application so I deploy it by running this main method